# Using {% cache %} tags around {% template %} includes (or in Header)

Tags: templating, craft3, cache, mysql, include

I was wondering if it makes sense to wrap these {% cache %} around {% include %} tags that call a separate file with params. Is it better to just include them in the actual file itself?

For example, I was using cache tags around includes that call main navigation HTML in the header, like so:

```
{% cache globally %}
  {% include '_partials/navigation/config.twig' with {
     menuLinks: menuNavLinks,
     direction: "right",
     type: "header" 
   }%}
{% endcache %}
```

This was causing an allocated memory error that took me forever to debug. FYI I am running locally on XAMPP and my memory_limit is set to 128M; when I increased this, it caused even more issues, related to Database Exception "MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away."

Is this not advised and against proper {% cache %} practices?

Answer (score 1):

General answer: It is not wrong to put `include` tags in `cache` tags.